# .innerHTML wont display image on safari iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, mobile-safari, innerhtml

Im using JS to change the innerHTML of a table row and replace it with a image source. It works fine on Chrome and on laptop but on iPhone safari, the images wont load. Any help appreciated!

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML='<img src='+JSON.stringify(obj[property].image_url)+'/>';
```

Comment: https://blog.johnmckerrell.com/2007/03/07/problems-with-safari-and-innerhtml/

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like:

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

var cellImg = document.createElement('img');
cellImg.setAttribute('src', JSON.stringify(obj[property].image_url);
cell2.appendChild(cellImg);
```

Comment: I'm pulling the image from an external API and the code you gave does not find the image, its like it appends the desired GET URL to my domain.

Comment: I edited my answer, want to try giving this one a go? @Fxghlu

Comment: yeah same result. I think its to do with the table on mobile screens. Finding it difficult to shrink it responsively and only using HTML/JS.

Comment: please try one more time, I was missing a single quote in my second line. If that doesn't work then I'm sorry to have wasted your time.